# How do I change the colours used in Resharper's preview windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, resharper

I'm using a dark theme in visual studio 2010, and have just set up Resharper's colours to fit that.

However, when I now use either the Inspection Results preview or the Find Usages preview, it has picked up the dark background colour setting but none of the other colour settings.  This makes it rather difficult to read, black on dark gray!

I have looked through the Resharper section of the visual studio colour settings, but I can't find one for the background of a preview window specifically, has anyone else found out how to change this please?

(Edit: I have no problem with setting just the background colour back to light gray/white, especially if it's not going to pick up the other colours, so I'm clarifying that even a fairly complicated method of setting just this one colour would be fine.)

Answer (score 11):

I was getting an all-white after changing to a dark theme in the Find Results but change the follow and worked for me.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Definition Window Background

Comment: Is there a way to change the text color? For example, for me the variable names are in black and are hard to read, however I can't change the foreground color on `Definition Window Background`.

Comment: @JeffBridgman - Make sure the Resharper color identifier is on in the Resharper settings. Then adjust the font and color settings that start with Resharper.    Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings -> Color Identifiers -> On.    Example in Font and Color: Resharper Class Identifier

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS2012, try switching to VS's built-in **Dark** theme to fix this problem.